# How to get full query text in mysql funtrion

Tags: mysql

I want  make a logs for my simple application. Could you tell me how to get full query text which is launched this trigger?

EX. In app I'm changing some user surname and I want to insert this query (update) by trigger to table logs. How to get text od this update query?

```
create trigger updatee
    after update on users
    for each row
    DELIMITER $$
    insert into logs values(null,now(),"Update",?QUERY?)
    DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: There seems to be a solution on dba.stackexchange: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/8112 Maybe you can adjust your trigger so it works

Comment: I write in in this way [code](http://wklej.to/nvhQC) but it don't work correctly [screen](http://screenshot.sh/odYHeR13HQYIx) its return internal query :/